# Syntax error with concat in trigger near signal statement

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-5.6, syntax, concat

Please help me with syntax for MySQL 5.6.

For some reason I get the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '('WRONG SOCIAL: ', new.social);
        end if;
        if not (new.photo is nul'
```

When trying to run this SQL code:

```
create table table_social (
        sid varchar(250) primary key,
        auth char(32) not null,
        social integer,               -- to be checked by triggers
        female boolean,
        given varchar(250) not null,
        family varchar(250) null,
        photo varchar(1000) null,     -- to be checked by triggers
        place varchar(250) null,
        ip varchar(250) not null,
        uid integer not null references 
            table_users(uid) on delete cascade
);

delimiter //

create trigger social_insert_trigger before insert on table_social
for each row begin
        if new.social < 0 OR new.social > 6 then
                signal sqlstate '45000' 
                set message_text = concat('WRONG SOCIAL: ', new.social);
        end if;
        if not (new.photo is null OR new.photo regexp '^https?://') then
                signal sqlstate '45000' 
                set message_text = concat('WRONG PHOTO: ', new.photo);
        end if;
end
//

create trigger social_update_trigger before update on table_social
for each row begin
        if new.social < 0 OR new.social > 6 then
                signal sqlstate '45000' 
                set message_text = concat('WRONG SOCIAL: ', new.social);
        end if;
        if not (new.photo is null OR new.photo regexp '^https?://') then
                signal sqlstate '45000' 
                set message_text = concat('WRONG PHOTO: ', new.photo);
        end if;
end
//
```

I tried removing `concat`, replacing single quotes by double quotes, splitting `signal` line in two (as above) and back - and still can not find out, what is wrong.

Comment: I don't have an instance to check this, but is it your delimiter? you have `^https?://`, maybe try using `$$` as a delimiter?

Comment: You have the delimiter set to `//` and there is some occurrences of `//` in your code... `^https?://`, for example

Comment: No, I have changed delimiter to `$$$` and it still errors out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Test this code:

```
drop table if EXISTS table_social;
create table table_social (
        sid varchar(250) primary key,
        auth char(32) not null,
        social integer,               -- to be checked by triggers
        female boolean,
        given varchar(250) not null,
        family varchar(250) null,
        photo varchar(1000) null,     -- to be checked by triggers
        place varchar(250) null,
        ip varchar(250) not null,
        uid integer not null references 
            table_users(uid) on delete cascade
);

delimiter //

create trigger social_insert_trigger before insert on table_social
for each row begin
        if new.social < 0 OR new.social > 6 then
                set @message_text = concat('WRONG SOCIAL: ', new.social);
                signal sqlstate '45000'
                set MESSAGE_TEXT = @message_text;
        end if;
        if not (new.photo is null OR new.photo regexp '^https?://') then
                set @message_text = concat('WRONG PHOTO: ', new.photo);
                signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = @message_text;
        end if;
end
//

create trigger social_update_trigger before update on table_social
for each row begin
        if new.social < 0 OR new.social > 6 then
                set @message_text = concat('WRONG SOCIAL: ', new.social);
                signal sqlstate '45000' 
                set message_text = @message_text;
        end if;
        if not (new.photo is null OR new.photo regexp '^https?://') then
                set @message_text = concat('WRONG PHOTO: ', new.photo);
                signal sqlstate '45000' 
                set message_text = @message_text;
        end if;
end
//
```

it not understand **CONCAT()** in **SIGNAL SQLSTATE SET message_text**